# Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

Please have a look at my code: I'm trying to create `myCar` with an Expression Tree.

I get an `ArgumentException` on this line `var m = Expression.Lambda<Func<Engine,...`
The message is *Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration*.

```
public class Engine
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Engine(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
public class Car
{
    private readonly Engine engine;
    public Car(Engine engine)
    {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    public string GetEngineName(){return engine.Name;}
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ci = typeof (Car).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof (Engine)});

        var engine = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Engine));

        var m = Expression.Lambda<Func<Engine,Car>>(Expression.New(ci, engine))
                          .Compile();

        var myCar = m(new Engine("TDI 2.0"));
        var s = myCar.GetEngineName();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong and where I did the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035287/linq-create-logical-inverse-of-expression

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must specify the engine in the 'params ParameterExpression[] parameters' part of Expression.Lambda

```
var m = Expression.Lambda<Func<Engine, Car>>(Expression.New(ci, engine), engine)
```