# How to Instantiate a Generic Type With Multiple Input Parameters?

Tags: c#, generics

I have 2 methods as following:

```
Method1(int a, int b)
{
    var type = Typ1(a, b);
}

Method2
{
    var type = Typ2(a, b);
}
```

I'd like to write a generic method which does the work:

```
GenericMethod<T>(int a, int b)
{
    var type = new T(a, b);
}
```

But T doesn't accept any input parameter. How could I achieve this?

I know using `Activator.Instance(T, a, b)` I can do that but it has a high performance cost.

I also know that I can call the default constructor of a generic type using T() then setting the properties,but in my case, I'd like to pass 2 parameters which are compulsory.

I don't want to introduce a constructor with no parameter.

Is there any way to do this with generics?

Thanks,

Comment: It should be noted that even if you do `new T()` on a generic type which was a `new()` constraint, the compiler will simply transform that to an `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` call, so there is no performance benefit. The only way around that is to use some kind of factory pattern, similar to what SLaks is doing with the delegate.

Answer (score 4):

Create your factory class:

```
    public static class TypeFactory<T>
{
    private static Func<int, int, T> Func { get; set; }

    static TypeFactory()
    {
        TypeFactory<Type1>.Func = (a, b) => new Type1(a, b);
        TypeFactory<Type2>.Func = (a, b) => new Type2(a, b);
    }

    public static T Create(int a, int b)
    {
        return Func(a, b);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
        var type1 = TypeFactory<Type1>.Create(1, 2);
        var type2 = TypeFactory<Type2>.Create(1, 2);
```

Comment: You shouldn't initialize it in the class itself.  Your initializer will run once per type parameter.

Comment: what would you suggest then? I can use a lock inside the class to make sure the static constructor only runs once but I doubt it will gain any performance benefit over Activator.CreateInstance<T>()?

Comment: have you got a code sample for this? I can't just move the static ctor out of the class. I mean I can move it but when should it be called and from where? I'd need it to be called only once throughout the application. I can put it in the Application_Start event!

Answer (score 2):

No.

Instead, you can accept a delegate that creates them for you:

```
GenericMethod<T>(int a, int b, Func<int, int, T> creator) {
    T t = creator(a, b);
}

GenericMethod(8, 9, (a, b) => new YourType(a, b));
```

You could also [store these creators in a generic static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686630/static-generic-class-as-dictionary):

```
static class Creator<T> {
    public static Func<int, int, T> Func { get; set; }
}
GenericMethod<T>(int a, int b) {
    T t = Creator<T>.Func(a, b);
}


Creator<YourType>.Func = (a, b) => new YourType(a, b);
```

Comment: I quite like the static generic class approach, thanks. Does it have the highest performance in comparison with other approaches?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Activator, you could use an expression tree. [Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758817/create-an-instance-of-a-class-with-expression-trees)

Comment: To make that worth doing, you need to store the compiled expression tree (eg, in a static generic dictionary, as in my answer) so that you can reuse it later.   Otherwise, it will end up being even slower.

Comment: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2010/04/02/don-t-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions.aspx Is this approach the fastest one?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you need to use a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). However, the only constructor constraint available is support for a parameterless constructor `where T : new()`.

If `Typ1` and `Typ2` share a base class which defines properties using the 2 integers or both support an interface guaranteeing setters for those integers you could define a parameterless constructor on each class and use an additional constraint to allow later access to the properties.

Comment: A constraint of T to the base type would not open up the constructors on T. For one, there is no guarantee that for a base with a parameterized constructor that the derived children *also* provide parameterized constructors.

Comment: Even with a `new()` constraint, the compiler just translates that into a call to `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`, so there's no performance gain. The only thing you gain is compile time checking for the presence of a constructor.

Comment: @Sven, where do you get that? I see no such evidence in the IL or the C# language specification on the constraint.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's required behaviour by the specification, but it is what both the Microsoft and Mono C# compilers do; you can check it with Reflector of ILSpy or something similar.

Comment: @Sven, SLaks, You know what, nevermind. I tested the wrong method. I see the IL on `return new T()` and `return Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` is the same. `return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T))` is markedly different.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class MyTypeFactory
{
    static MyTypeFactory()
    {
        MethodRunner<Type1>.Func = (a, b) => new Type1(a, b);
        MethodRunner<Type2>.Func = (a, b) => new Type2(a, b);
    }

    public static T Create<T>(int a, int b)
    {
        return MethodRunner<T>.Func(a, b);
    }

    static class MethodRunner<T>
    {
        public static Func<int, int, T> Func { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This looks promising?!

is a static ctor thread-safe by nature (CLR) like static field initializers?

Comment: Yes.  Static field initializers are compiled into the static ctor.