# Linq: Create logical inverse of expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I would like to create a method that accepts an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and creates the logical inverse of it (i.e. it would return `false` where it would have returned `true`, and vice versa. This is much harder than I thought. This is where I am up to:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(expression.Body));
}
```

This compiles fine but throws the following Exception when called:

```
Test method Tests.Common.Unit.LinqPredicateBuilderTests.CanInverseAPredicate threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration
```

I have no idea what I'm doing. Could anyone fill in the blanks?

Comment: inverse is a bit misleading. I understand that as calculating the input from the output.

Comment: My apologies. My terminology is not quite up to speed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're calling `Expression.Lambda` to create an expression with no parameters at all, when you should be forwarding the single parameter of the source expression.

Note that we are trying to create an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and not an  `Expression<Func<bool>>`.

Try this instead:

```
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(expression.Body),
                                        expression.Parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks! This has passed my only unit test so far! I'm going to write a couple more, and if it's all good, I'll give you your dues!

Comment: Is there any difference from this to getting an inverse from an `IQueryable`?

Comment: @cottsak: Could you clarify what you mean? An `IQueryable` doesn't really have any intuitive definition of an 'inverse'. You could of course use the above technique to reverse a `where` clause or similar in the process of constructing a queryable.

Comment: Hi Ani. Having thought about this more since the comment, I think I am trying to compare an expression tree to an `IQueryable`, not a single expression lambda. If an expression tree is a collection of predicates, is an `IQueryable` also essentially?

Comment: Make my day! Thx Ani